# Array_push is only giving one value from an sql query?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have an sql query which is fetching the data in format :
Date                         comment
12-3-2016           local meeting

and so-on..

I am using array_push for values so that i can display them in a page but i am only getting one value value from using array_push. here is my code:

```
$res = mysqli_fetch_array($r);      
    $result = array();  

    array_push($result,array(
        "Date"=>$res['date'],
        "Events"=>$res['comment']
        )
    );      
//using JSON 
    echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result)); 
    mysqli_close($con);
```

The output which i am getting is like this:

```
{"result": [{"Date": "12-3-2016","Events": "Parent Teacher Meeting"}]}
```

Comment: You are only pushing one item onto the `$result` array with `array_push`. That is why you only get one item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqli_fetch_array($r)` fetches **one** row from a result set. To get **all** rows from a result set, you should use `while`-loop:

```
$result = array();   
while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {  // here, a while-loop
    array_push($result,array(
        "Date" => $res['date'],
        "Events" => $res['comment']
    ));      
}

//using JSON 
echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result)); 
mysqli_close($con);
```